# A family of non-Lipschitzian functions with a prescribed number of global minimuns

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to construct a family o continuous functions but not Lipschitzians, defined on $[0,1]^{n}$,  with a prescribed number of global minimums and "many" local minimuns.

For instance, consider

$$ F:=\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-a_{i}|^{r_{i}}:a_{i},r_{i}\in (0,1)\} ,$$
then given any $f(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})\in F$, is clear that $f$ is not Lipschitzian, and has one global minimum at $(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n})$.

How can I define a family "like" $F$ but with a prefixed number of global minimums (say, 1,2,..., m)? Some idea?

Also if I want to add "many" local minimums to such function, Maybe adding some trigonometric function?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $k$ point $a_1,...,a_k \in (0,1)^n$. Then define

$$F:[0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$F(x):=\min_{i\in\{1,...,n\}}||x-a_i||^\alpha, \quad 0 <\alpha <1$$

---

If we want add $a_{n+1}$ as a local minimum in $a_{n+1}$ consider 
$$G(x):=\min \{F(x), ||x-a_{n+1}||+\frac{1}{2}\}$$

Comment: Thanks Leonardo Vannini! Each $a_{k}$ is then a global optimum. How can I add some local minimums?

Comment: @user123043 ok, now it should be correct and complete.

Comment: Great Leonardo Vannini! Thanks!